# How to use nginx with same host but different url for diff sites

Tags: nginx, web-server, redhat

I have different webistes serving on ports  8080, 8090

Now The only port i am allowed is 8085 from outside.

Is it possible to do that

```
myserver.com:8085/site1   go to 8080
myserver.com:8085/site2   go to 8090
```

I want that

`http://www.myserver.com:8085/site1`   should go to `http://myserver.com:8080/site1`

*Edit by Tim - added from OP question belowA*

I would also like

```
/site1/task
```

to proxy to
    http://example.com:5678/task

I tried this

```
location ~ ^/site2(/)?(?<var>\w+)? {
  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3434/$var;
}
```

Comment: Yes! See: http://nginx.org/r/proxy_pass

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should work - this is bare bones only. This is hardly a professional question though, this is an absolute basic of Nginx that you should be able to work out yourself with a simple tutorial.

```
server {
  server_name example.com;
  listen 8085;

  location /site1 {
    proxy_pass http://example.com:8080;
  }

  location /site1/task {
    proxy_pass http://example.com/task:8090;
  }

  location /site2 {
    proxy_pass http://example.com:8090;
  }

  # If you want a variable in the location, something like this might work
  # This is a regular expression with a capture group, untested, which 
  # should at least give you a good clue how to work it out yourself
  location ~/site3/([0-9a-zA-Z_\-\s\+]+)$) {
    proxy_pass http://example.com/$1;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that is working . I can see the website but all link on that site and css files are relative to hostname not /site1. also i also want to go like  `/site1/task` to go to `http://example.com:5678/task`. I tried this `location ~ ^/site2(/)?(?<var>\w+)? {
           proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3434/$var;
     }`

Comment: If you have another question, ask another question, don't try to tack it on. You can edit your question if you think it's part of the same question, too hard to read configuration in a comment.

Comment: I have added detail in question

Comment: You didn't copy your comment into the question, so I've copied your comment into your question. I've updated my answer to answer the question you asked, but based on your proposed answer I suspect you didn't ask the question you meant to. Please be precise when you ask questions. Saying "it didn't work" doesn't help - say what didn't work, show error or access logs, and describe both what it was meant to do and what it really did.

Comment: hi tim , thanks for that . The problem is if web page at site1 refers to `/static` then it goes to `host/static` but i want it to go to `host/site1/static`. is it possible

Comment: You need to make your questions much more precise, and make sure the actual question is edited and kept up to date. Look at the part of my answer around site3, that might answer your question, but I'm not sure, everything you've said has some ambiguity.